# codeigniter cannot load library

Tags: codeigniter, controller, load

I have a problem that I can't load my library in my controller :S

I got this error: Message: Undefined property: Profil::$profileWall

My library:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class ProfileWall
{

    private $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function wallShow()
    {
        $this->CI->load->model('profil_model');
        return $this->CI->profil_model->wallGet($this->CI->uri->segment(3));
    }
}
```

and my controller

```
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('profil_model');
        $data['query'] = $this->profil_model->vis_profil($this->uri->segment(3)); 


        //Henter lib profilwall så man kan vise wall beskeder i profilen
        $this->load->library('profileWall');
        $data['queryWall'] = $this->profileWall->wallShow();



        $data['content'] = 'profil_view';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);


}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which version of CI are you using? and where have you saved `Profilewall.php`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Make sure your library loading is always done in lowercase, per the [Documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html), object instances will always be lower case.

Also make sure your library file is capitalized `ProfileWall.php`

example load `$this->load->library('profilewall');`

usage `$this->profilewall->function();`

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH :D it was just profilewall then i load the library so only lowercase :D

Comment: Thanks so much! I never knew this, and had wasted a day. I'll rtfm more now. :)

Comment: Can we disable these Codeigniter naming conventions? Because I am from Java background and want to use Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 2):

Library in code igniter didn't concentrate for lower case, 
Have you placed your library in folder application/library? before
or try changed your class name with CI_ProfileWall

Answer (score 1):

I have been saved my files with CKEditor CKFinder in /libraries folder.
I changed with first letter of CKFinder to Ckfinder and CKEditor to Ckeditor.
Working fine.

In your profileWall , it should be Profilewall

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after straggling alot I realized that I was loading my libraries in a wrong format. I was not putting them into an `array`. I changed 
`$this->load->library('email','custom');` to `$this->load->library(array('email','custom'));`.