# I have issue in Codeigniter 3.0 with codeof __autoload function

Tags: php, codeigniter, autoload

I have issue in Codeigniter 3.0 with codeof __autoload function in config/config.php It keeps giving the following error

> Class 'Frontend_Controller' not found

**core/MY_Controller.php**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**libraries/Frontend_Controller.php**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Frontend_Controller extends MY_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**libraries/Admin_Controller.php**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**controllers/Welcome.php**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends Frontend_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**config/config.php**

```
function __autoload($class) {
    $path = array('libraries');

    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0) {
        foreach($path as $dir) {
        $file = APPPATH.$dir.'/'.($class).'.php';
        if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file))
            @include_once($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776399/codeigniter-cannot-load-library

Answer (score 1):

this code work for me for spl_autoload_register()

```
function autoload($classname)
       {
        $path = array('libraries');
        if(strpos($classname, 'CI_') !== 0)
       {
            foreach($path as $dir)
              {
                $file = APPPATH.$dir.'/'.($classname).'.php';
                if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file))
                @include_once($file);
              }
        }
    }
 spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

Answer (score 0):

It was due to my config.php file setting $config['composer_autoload'] was TRUE which(Composer)  prevents MY_ controllers from loading __autoload function. 
i used spl_autoload_register. e.g.:

`function customCIAutoload($classname){
    $path = array('libraries');
    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0) {
        foreach($path as $dir) {
        $file = APPPATH.$dir.'/'.($class).'.php';
        if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file))
            @include_once($file);
        }
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('customCIAutoload');`